# Why can´t I select an element created with a JQuery event (append)?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I wrote somthing like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="item">An Item</div>
<body>
```

I created this with a jQuery event.

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $(body).append("<div class="item>An Item</div>");
});
```

so now i have something like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="item">An Item</div>
  <div class="item">A New Item Created With jQuery Event</div>
</body>
```

The problem: I want to do this, to get the info from both divs.

```
$(".item").click(function(){

  $(this).text();

});
```

Works fine with the original *.item* from the HTML. But it doesnt work with the newly created element with jQuery. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use .on('click')

```
$(document).on('click','.item',function(){

 console.log ($(this).text());

});
```

Comment: Wow, that's great. Thank You. Sorry about this being a duplicate post, I did't know how to search for it.

Comment: @FYP89 don worry man  .. and it will be better if you take a look at the duplicated question as well .. good luck to you